# Mysql error 1064.PHP when select data with forward slashes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I try to execute this query with PHP. but mysql server is giving to error like this.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index='CEA/EO/MA/0001'' at line 1. What is the reason for that?

My PHP code part is

```
$index = ($_POST['index']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE index='CEA/EO/MA/0001'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: who is the vote down this??

Comment: MySQL is actually usually very good at saying exactly which word is in error in the statement by showing it first in the "near" part, here it's `index` (being a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html))

Comment: The problem is that `index` is a reserved word.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close (although I do not downvote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. If you're going to name a column `index` you *wrap* it in backticks:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE `index`='CEA/EO/MA/0001'";
```

---

Refer to the following page for the full list of MySQL reserved words:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**